# Meaning of Semicontinuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, terminology

could somebody explain to me what semi-continuous is?
I read my textbook, Wikipedia and look for explanation on the internet but I couldn't find anything helpful.

At first glance it seems like right/left continuity but it is not.

Definition: We say that a functional $\Phi:X \rightarrow R$ is lower semicontinuous if for any sequence $(u_k)$ in $X$ converging strongly to $u$ we have $$\Phi(u) \leqslant lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} inf  \Phi(u_k)$$

1) Particularly, how do I intepret $inf  \Phi(u_k)$?

Thank you

Comment: It should be noted that $\liminf_{k\to \infty}$ is not the same as $\lim_{k\to\infty} \lim$.  Specifically, $\liminf_{k\to\infty} u_k = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\inf\{ u_n : n \ge k\}\right)$.

Comment: [This image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Lower_semi.svg/220px-Lower_semi.svg.png) is likely helpful, only imagine that the domain is $X$ and not $\Bbb R$.